# LibGDX Gradle: Gradle is getting my root project directory wrong?

Tags: gradle, libgdx

I'm really new to Gradle and I've been trying to learn to use gradlew commands. In Mac Terminal, I run this:

```
kenneths-air:~ kennethwang$ /Users/kennethwang/Desktop/WHP2-New/gradlew ios:launchIOSDevice
```

WHP2-New is my root project directory and I have all my projects inside: whp2-new-core, whp2-new-ios, whp2-new-android, whp2-new-desktop.

However, I get this in my output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'ios' not found in root project 'kennethwang'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Here is my output with the --info parameter

```
kenneths-air:~ kennethwang$ /Users/kennethwang/Desktop/WHP2-New/gradlew ios:launchIOSDevice --info
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using empty build file.
Included projects: [root project 'kennethwang']
Evaluating root project 'kennethwang' using empty build file.
All projects evaluated.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'ios' not found in root project 'kennethwang'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more     log output.
```

It seems like it thinks my root directory is in the wrong folder and I honestly have no idea even after googling for a few hours on how to set it to the right directory.

Here is my settings.gradle. Originally rootProject.name wasnt there, but I added it in and it still doesn't work.

```
rootProject.name = ‘WHP2-new’
include 'desktop', 'android', 'ios', 'core'
```

gradlew and settings.gradle and everything else are all in WHP2-New folder. I am seriously lost here, can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cd into `/Users/kennethwang/Desktop/WHP2-New/`, and then run the build from there.